# CSS calc() doesn't work on Chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have div which have id name is #monthlyconfirm_grid. I used that jQuery process to control scroll from gridview but it works only for IE and doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var expi = $("#monthlyconfirm_grid").scrollLeft - 2;
        var expr = "calc("+ expi +")";
        $(".locked").css("left", expr);
});
```

P.S: I used `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` to work on IE.

Why it doesn't work on chrome and Firefox? How can I solve that?

Comment: `scrollLeft` is a function not a property; so use it like `scrollLeft()`. And title and body of question is not in sync

Comment: tested..but still didn't work on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: If you're using jquery anyway, why are you trying to then use css calc to change the laft position? just use jquery isntead

Comment: it should be `calc(100% - YOUR_VALUE)`

Comment: yes, I want to use only JQuery but only JQuery cannot freeze columns from asp:gridview(BoundsField).

Comment: why do you need to use calc when you already computed the value in expi?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* property: calc(expression) */
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

Try like this and make sure corresponding parent elements has proper width